# How to create a table within a legend with overflow-x

Tags: html, css

can someone tell me how i can create a table within a legend which creates a scrollbar if th its bigger than the div in which is it.

```
<div style="width:700px;">
<h1>wefwfwfwef</h1>
<fieldset>
    <div style="width:700px;">
    <label>sdfsdfsdj dfsdfsdfsdj sdfsdfsdfsdfsdj sdfsdfsdfsdfsdj sdfsdf</label>
    <table style="background-color:white;color:black;"> <!-- This table should only be 700 px width... without width definition (because its display:block)-->
        <tr>
            <td>ehehef<td>
            <td>ehehef<td>
            <td>ehehef<td>
            <td>ehehef<td>
            <td>ehehef<td>
            <td>ehehef<td>
            <td>ehehef<td>
            <td>ehehef<td>
            <td>ehehef<td>
            <td>ehehef<td>
            <td>ehehef<td>
            <td>ehehef<td>
            <td>ehehef<td>
            <td>ehehef<td>
            <td>ehehef<td>
            <td>ehehef<td>
            <td>ehehef<td>
            <td>ehehef<td>
            <td>ehehef<td>
            <td>ehehef<td>
            <td>ehehef<td>
            <td>ehehef<td>
            <td>ehehef<td>
            <td>ehehef<td>
            <td>ehehef<td>
            <td>ehehef<td>
            <td>ehehef<td>
            <td>ehehef<td>
            <td>ehehef<td>
            <td>ehehef<td>
            <td>ehehef<td>
            <td>ehehef<td>
            <td>ehehef<td>
            <td>ehehef<td>
            <td>ehehef<td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
</fieldset>
<div style="width: 100%;background-color:black;overflow-x:auto;">
    <table style="background-color:white;color:black;display:block"> 
        <tr>
            <td>ehehef<td>
            <td>ehehef<td>
            <td>ehehef<td>
            <td>ehehef<td>
            <td>ehehef<td>
            <td>ehehef<td>
            <td>ehehef<td>
            <td>ehehef<td>
            <td>ehehef<td>
            <td>ehehef<td>
            <td>ehehef<td>
            <td>ehehef<td>
            <td>ehehef<td>
            <td>ehehef<td>
            <td>ehehef<td>
            <td>ehehef<td>
            <td>ehehef<td>
            <td>ehehef<td>
            <td>ehehef<td>
            <td>ehehef<td>
            <td>ehehef<td>
            <td>ehehef<td>
            <td>ehehef<td>
            <td>ehehef<td>
            <td>ehehef<td>
            <td>ehehef<td>
            <td>ehehef<td>
            <td>ehehef<td>
            <td>ehehef<td>
            <td>ehehef<td>
            <td>ehehef<td>
            <td>ehehef<td>
            <td>ehehef<td>
            <td>ehehef<td>
            <td>ehehef<td>
        </tr>
    </table>
<div>
</div>
```

Comment: Add a height to the containing div.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? http://jsbin.com/ubomo4

If yes just add `overflow-x:scroll;` in the css properties of the `div` under the `fieldset`.