# HTML/CSS: How to create scrollbar for tr

Tags: html, css

Can someone tell me how to create a scrollbar for the inner table? The inner table is not displayed within the container. I colored the background of the container yellow. The table itself is blue.

I wanna see a scroll bar within the table.

Source:
http://nopaste.info/e51385254e.html

and here:

```
<html>
<body>
<div style="width:1000px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;background-color: yellow; height: 1000px;">
    <table style="background-color: blue">
        <tr>
            <th>column1</th>
            <th>column2</th>
            <th>column3</th>
            <th>column4</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>columnvalue1</td>
            <td>columnvalue2</td>
            <td>columnvalue3</td>
            <td>columnvalue4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th>SubColumn1</th>
                        <th>SubColumn2</th>
                        <th>SubColumn3</th>
                        <th>SubColumn4</th>
                        <th>SubColumn5</th>
                        <th>SubColumn6</th>
                        <th>SubColumn7</th>
                        <th>SubColumn8</th>
                        <th>SubColumn9</th>
                        <th>SubColumn10</th>
                        <th>SubColumn11</th>
                        <th>SubColumn12</th>
                        <th>SubColumn13</th>
                        <th>SubColumn14</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>subvalue1</td>
                        <td>subvalue2</td>
                        <td>subvalue3</td>
                        <td>subvalue4</td>
                        <td>subvalue5</td>
                        <td>subvalue6</td>
                        <td>subvalue7</td>
                        <td>subvalue8</td>
                        <td>subvalue9</td>
                        <td>subvalue10</td>
                        <td>subvalue11</td>
                        <td>subvalue12</td>
                        <td>subvalue13</td>
                        <td>subvalue14</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<body>
</html>
```

Comment: Which part is the "inner table?"

Comment: use find :D lol :D  I had to look twice too ...de

Comment: are you trying to do this from past 3 days ? : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4898187/how-to-create-a-table-within-a-legend-with-overflow-x

I see that you answer by @Kyle Sevenoaks works there.. it is almost similar here too!!

Answer (score 8):

wrap your inner table with a div. Make that div scrollable by giving it the width and height styles with overflow as auto or scroll.

```
<div style="width:1000px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;background-color: yellow; height: 1000px;">
<table style="background-color: blue">
    <tr>
        <th>column1</th>
        <th>column2</th>
        <th>column3</th>
        <th>column4</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>columnvalue1</td>
        <td>columnvalue2</td>
        <td>columnvalue3</td>
        <td>columnvalue4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4">
            <div style="max-height: 100px; max-width: 100px; width: 100px; overflow: auto;">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>SubColumn1</th>
                    <th>SubColumn2</th>
                    <th>SubColumn3</th>
                    <th>SubColumn4</th>
                    <th>SubColumn5</th>
                    <th>SubColumn6</th>
                    <th>SubColumn7</th>
                    <th>SubColumn8</th>
                    <th>SubColumn9</th>
                    <th>SubColumn10</th>
                    <th>SubColumn11</th>
                    <th>SubColumn12</th>
                    <th>SubColumn13</th>
                    <th>SubColumn14</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>subvalue1</td>
                    <td>subvalue2</td>
                    <td>subvalue3</td>
                    <td>subvalue4</td>
                    <td>subvalue5</td>
                    <td>subvalue6</td>
                    <td>subvalue7</td>
                    <td>subvalue8</td>
                    <td>subvalue9</td>
                    <td>subvalue10</td>
                    <td>subvalue11</td>
                    <td>subvalue12</td>
                    <td>subvalue13</td>
                    <td>subvalue14</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

that should work

Comment: yes your last post is what i want to do, but without giving a width. is that possible?

Comment: yes, you could remove width, max-width, max-height and instead make overflow: scroll, but at some point you'll feel the necessity of defining width and height. just give it a try :)

Answer (score 4):

Try this on div part

```
<div style="overflow:scroll width:1000px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;
background-color: yellow; height: 1000px;">
```

If fail, try overflow:scroll on the style of the table.

Comment: Sorry for the double, I've flagged mine for deletion.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your table with a div, which will have the same width with your `container` and `overflow:scroll`

Example: http://jsbin.com/uheha4

Comment: wow..  I didn't know about jsbin... that's cool thing :) thanks :)

Comment: I knew about jsfiddle.net, but jsbin is new for me :) Thanks for this enlightenment :)