# Scrolling table cell with 100% table height

Tags: html, css

I need a table to take up 100% of the page with 2 cells side-by-side and the cell on the right with the ability to scroll overflow content.

Here is a working example of what I need:
https://jsfiddle.net/way0316f/1/
The only difference between that fiddle and what I need is that the second TD tag specifies height in pixels instead of percentages:

```
<td style="border:1px solid green; height:400px">
```

After reading some of the comments it is becoming clear that this is a Firefox issue, and that it works in Chrome. What seems to be the problem is that overflow in the table cells never gets triggered as long as the heights are set using percentages. When the heights are set using pixels (as in the fiddle) then overflow gets triggered as expected.

So even with everything set to 100% height (including html and body tags) the table will still expand to greater than 100% of the window and no overflow ever gets triggered.

Comment: `<td style="border:1px solid green;" height="100%">` Did you try this?

Comment: Is there are reason why you don't want to just change the height of the inner div instead? This does work: https://jsfiddle.net/way0316f/1/

Comment: @Coldspeed Of course I tried that. I've tried many many different things and I mentioned in the question itself that when I set the height to 100% the total table height goes beyond 100% of the window. I need the table to stay fixed at 100% and only that 1 particular cell should scroll. Doing your suggestion doesn't use the cells overflow at all, it just makes the whole page scrollable. EDIT: It occurs to me this might be browser specific, so I should mention that I'm using Firefox.

Comment: @puelo I know that works, I said in my question that it works. It just doesn't work with 100% height. Everything needs to take up 100% of the page and just that one cell on the right needs to scroll if there's overflow, that's all I want. I can't set the height in pixels because not everyones browser has the exact same pixel height.

Comment: Not too sure if I understand your problem, [is this what you need](https://jsfiddle.net/way0316f/9/)?

Comment: @MathijsFlietstra No because that is the entire page scrolling, not the table cell. The scroll bar is outside the table and when you scroll down you can tell the entire table goes up because the "Side Menu" cell also goes up. I just want the one cell inside the green border on the right to go from top to bottom (100% of the page) and become scrollable when the content overflows. Just the cell should scroll, not the entire page.

Comment: Ah I see, it does indeed work different in Firefox, In Chrome it's only the table cell scrolling now.. I'll see if I can fix it for Firefox.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML/CSS: How to create scrollbar for tr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4919629/html-css-how-to-create-scrollbar-for-tr)

Comment: @polkovnikov.ph That is a separate issue because all the table heights are set using pixels, not percentages. I have updated my original question to reflect that I now suspect this is a Firefox specific issue. Chrome apparently behaves as expected, but Firefox doesn't trigger an overflow in the table cells if the heights are set using percentages.

Comment: The real problem is usage of tables for markup. Tables are meant to make tables. They were used for markup in 90's. They're extremely hard to reason about due to major browser incompatibilities. Consider using `<div>`s.

Comment: @polkovnikov.ph That is a reasonable answer I suppose. However, I was hoping to avoid divs because I wanted a relatively simple page that could look ok in as many different browsers as possible. There are some that don't properly display divs side by side (like Dillo). I wanted the scrolling to work properly in mainstream browsers but even if it doesn't work in obscure ones using a table still at least ensures things are aligned properly.

Comment: Then I advise to put a `<div>` into each of your `<tr>`s, and try to set most of the styles on `<div>`s. This approach is used most of the times when people have to deal with tables, because otherwise it's almost impossible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works in both Chrome and Firefox.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

table {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

tr {
  vertical-align: top;
}

td:first-child {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 50%;
}

td:last-child {
  border: 1px solid green;
  position: relative;
}

td:last-child > div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Side Menu</td>
      <td>
        <div>
          Scrollable Cell
          <br> Scrollable Cell
          <br> Scrollable Cell
          <br> Scrollable Cell
          <br> Scrollable Cell
          <br> Scrollable Cell
          <br> Scrollable Cell
          <br> Scrollable Cell
          <br> Scrollable Cell
          <br> Scrollable Cell
          <br> Scrollable Cell
          <br> Scrollable Cell
          <br> Scrollable Cell
          <br> Scrollable Cell
          <br> Scrollable Cell
          <br> Scrollable Cell
          <br> Scrollable Cell
          <br> Scrollable Cell
          <br> Scrollable Cell
          <br> Scrollable Cell
          <br> Scrollable Cell
          <br> Scrollable Cell
          <br> Scrollable Cell
          <br> Scrollable Cell
          <br> Scrollable Cell
          <br> Scrollable Cell
          <br> Scrollable Cell
          <br> Scrollable Cell
          <br> Scrollable Cell
          <br> Scrollable Cell
          <br> Scrollable Cell
          <br> Scrollable Cell
          <br> Scrollable Cell
          <br> Scrollable Cell
          <br> Scrollable Cell
          <br> Scrollable Cell
          <br> Scrollable Cell
          <br> Scrollable Cell
          <br> Scrollable Cell
          <br> Scrollable Cell
          <br> Scrollable Cell
          <br> Scrollable Cell
          <br> Scrollable Cell
          <br> Scrollable Cell
          <br> Scrollable Cell
          <br> Scrollable Cell
          <br> Scrollable Cell
          <br> Scrollable Cell
          <br> Scrollable Cell
          <br> Scrollable Cell
          <br> Scrollable Cell
          <br> Scrollable Cell
          <br> Scrollable Cell
          <br> Scrollable Cell
          <br> Scrollable Cell
          <br> Scrollable Cell
          <br> Scrollable Cell
          <br> Scrollable Cell
          <br> Scrollable Cell
          <br> Scrollable Cell
          <br> Scrollable Cell
          <br> Scrollable Cell
          <br> Scrollable Cell
          <br> Scrollable Cell
          <br> Scrollable Cell
          <br> Scrollable Cell
          <br> Scrollable Cell
          <br> Scrollable Cell
          <br> Scrollable Cell
          <br> Scrollable Cell
          <br> Scrollable Cell
          <br> Scrollable Cell
          <br> Scrollable Cell
          <br> Scrollable Cell
          <br> Scrollable Cell
          <br> Scrollable Cell
          <br> Scrollable Cell
          <br> Scrollable Cell
          <br> Scrollable Cell
          <br> Scrollable Cell
          <br> Scrollable Cell
          <br>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a div element controlling the size the table can fit in.

```
<div style="height:400px">
```

When changing it to 100%, it fits the left column because the other one can scroll. When I changed the height to 1080px it fitted the screen. You can see my work [here.](https://jsfiddle.net/way0316f/11/)

Comment: That's still just making the entire **page** scroll. I want the **cell** to scroll. But maybe this is browser dependent? On your screen is the scrollbar inside the green border? On my screen your example doesn't have a scrollable cell, the scrollbar is outside the table and it simple makes the entire table scroll up.

Comment: Another comment just suggested that it behaves differently in Chrome than it does in Firefox. So maybe that's why it doesn't seem to work for me. I'm using FIrefox.

Comment: you can add overflow: auto; to the style for the div and any cell. overflow-y:school; is for vertical and overflow-x: scroll; is for horizontal scrolling

Comment: The overflow doesn't get triggered in Firefox. That's the problem. It only gets triggered when the heights are set using pixels. Once the heights are set using percentages it's like the table and cells have no idea how big the window actually is, so the table just expands past 100% of the window and never triggers any overflow.